# Can't run kubectl in docker container from a host machine installed Minikube "The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:32768 was refused"

Tags: macos, docker, kubernetes, kubectl

I want to have a container that can access and run kubectl command on my host machine. Here is what  I have:

- I have installed Kubernetes and Minikube on my host machine.
- I used this docker container: `helm-kubectl` [link](https://github.com/dtzar/helm-kubectl)

This is the command I run my docker:

```
docker run -it -v ~/.kube:/root/.kube -v ~/.minikube:/Users/xxxx/.minikube dtzar/helm-kubectl
```

Inside the container, when I checked the cluster, I can see the context has loaded my minikube, However, I can't run another kubectl command due to the reason "**The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:32768 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?**".

```
bash-5.0# kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME                                                           CLUSTER                                                        AUTHINFO                                                       NAMESPACE
          docker-desktop                                                 docker-desktop                                                 docker-desktop
          docker-for-desktop                                             docker-desktop                                                 docker-desktop
*         minikube                                                       minikube                                                       minikube
bash-5.0# kubectl get all
The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:32768 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I have checked my Kubenetes config at `~/.kube` and the port is 32768.

```
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /Users/xxx/.minikube/ca.crt
    server: https://127.0.0.1:32768
  name: minikube
```

I have tried port -p 32768 or --expose 32768 but no luck. So anyone can help this?

Comment: Unless you specify a host network for your container - localhost would be container-local.

Comment: Thank you, I added the `--network host` and it works!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks zerkms! It works with `--network host`